# How can send DM for unban command used user?

Tags: discord.js

I'm developing an unban command for a ban command.

When the ban is lifted, I want the embed message **unbanEmbeduserside** to be sent to the banned user via private message. This embed message will let the banned user know about it.

The codes for my unban command are as follows. Thanks in advance to my friends who will help me with how to write a code so that I can perform the operation I mentioned in the above article.

```
async run (bot, message, args) {
    message.delete(message.author);
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS"))
    return message.author.send("Buna yetkin yok.")

    let unbanEmbednotfoundmessage = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(0xdb2727)
    .setDescription(`Kullanıcı bulunamadı veya yasaklı değil.`);

    let userID = args[0]
    message.guild.fetchBans().then(bans => {
    if(bans.size == 0) return message.channel.send(unbanEmbednotfoundmessage);

    let bUser = bans.find(b => b.user.id == userID)
    if(!bUser) return message.channel.send(unbanEmbednotfoundmessage)

    let unbanEmbeduserside = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor('YASAKLAMA KALDIRILDI', 'https://i.hizliresim.com/midfo22.jpg')
    .setDescription(`
    *Yasaklamanız kaldırıldı, sunucuya tekrar katılabilirsiniz!*
    Yasaklamayı Kaldıran Yetkili: **${message.author.username}**
    `)
    .setColor(0xc8b280)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('gtaplus Multiplayer Community');

    let unbanEmbedserverside = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor('YASAKLAMA KALDIRMA', 'https://i.hizliresim.com/midfo22.jpg')
    .setDescription(`
    Yasağı Kaldırılan Kullanıcı: **${userID}**
    Yasaklamayı Kaldıran Yetkili: **${message.author.username}**
    `)
    .setColor(0xc8b280)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('gtaplus Multiplayer Community');

    message.guild.members.unban(bUser.user).then(() => message.channel.send(`**${userID}** yasaklaması kaldırıldı.`));

    if (unbanEmbedserverside){
        const log = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'server-log')
        log.send(unbanEmbedserverside);
    }
    })
}}
```

Comment: You can send the DM to the banned user like that `bUser.user.send(unbanEmbeduserside);`.

Comment: @SkulaurunMrusal The code doesn't work, probably for the reason MisterCheezeCake said. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Discord, any user, including a bot, will need to be in a server with a user to send them direct messages. This, unfortunately, means that unless the bot shares a server with the banned user, you will not be able to send the message. If the bot does share another server, the answer that Skularun Mrusal provided in the comments of your post should work.

Comment: I tried the code you mentioned. It didn't work, probably for the reason you said. Thanks.